# XFC0009 No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "ItemsSource", 48

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, binding

I have been trying to create a picker in Xamarin forms that would allow me to create if statements based on what a user selected from the picker. Which lead me to this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_0XDyy4ef8. I did everything the way the person in the video did it but Xamarin is adamant that  ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding CampusName}" cant interact with the CampusName like it can in the video. I have commented out some parts of the code because they are irrelevant to the question. The first code block is the viewmodel which gets CampusID and CampusName from my class Campus, the second code block. Third block is my relevant xaml. Can anyone either tell me why I am getting this XFC0009 or just straight up how to make an if statement based on picker input?

```
  class AboutViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

        public IList<Campus> CampList { get; set; }



        public AboutViewModel()
        {


            try
            {
                CampList = new ObservableCollection<Campus>
                {
                    new Campus { CampusID = 1, CampusName = "Cardiff" },
                    new Campus { CampusID = 2, CampusName = "Treforest" },
                    new Campus { CampusID = 3, CampusName = "Glyntaff" },
                    new Campus { CampusID = 4, CampusName = "Newport" }
                };

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }





           //itle = "About";
           //penWebCommand = new Command(async () => await Browser.OpenAsync("https://aka.ms/xamain-quickstart"));
        }
        
        //    CampusesList = GetCampuses().OrderBy(t => t.CampusName).ToList();

         // public ICommand OpenWebCommand { get; }
    }
```

```
namespace USW_Pathfinder.Models
{
    public class Campus
    {
        public int CampusID { get; set; }
        public string CampusName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

```
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:AboutViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>


 <Picker Title="--Select--"
  ItemsSource="Binding CampList}"
  ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding CampusName}"/>
```

Comment: Hi, your missing parentheses ({) in below line of code. recheck once i.e ItemsSource="Binding CampList}"

Comment: Thank you man! I would love to upvote everyone who has been helping me but stack overflow wont let me me yet. Thank though!